# Error in SQL statement : Assertion error : Found duplicate rewrite attributes

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am executing a Minus query in data bricks between two tables which has same columns and datatypes.
But it throwing me an assertion error : Found duplicate rewrite attributes.
I done see any duplicate column names present in both the tables. Please suggest/guide me
Thanks in advance

I have tried validating the column names, data types, duplicate column entry. all looks good

Comment: *But it throwing me an assertion error : Found duplicate rewrite attributes.* This is NOT MySQL error message. Remove wrong tag.

Comment: please add query & detailed error message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.